# I tried to deploy a Web app with Vnet Intergration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

When I am deploying the arm template to azure portal function app is deploying but the vnet integration was not created

I tried deploying a web app but vnet integration was not creating. I am expecting to create a connection between the web app and vnet

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error details or the template which you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, I am not supposed to share the template.

Comment: Can i provide you with a sample template ?

Comment: @Jai Vivaan refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-resource-manager-templates) for sample examples on [how create webapp with regional vnet integration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-regional-vnet-integration).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- I have to deploy a sample Arm template which conations web app, Vnet by using below ARM template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
        "_generator": {
            "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.5.6.12127",
      "templateHash": "11940660712182553101"
        }
    },
  "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "location of all the resources."
      }
        },
    "appName": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)]",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the app to create."
      }
        }
    },
  "variables": {
        "appServicePlanName": "[format('{0}{1}', parameters('appName'), uniqueString(subscription().subscriptionId))]",
    "vnetName": "[format('{0}vnet', parameters('appName'))]",
    "vnetAddressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetName": "[format('{0}sn', parameters('appName'))]",
    "subnetAddressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "appServicePlanSku": "S1"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanSku')]"
      },
      "kind": "app"
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                  "[variables('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
              ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
                "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
                    "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
              "delegations": [
                {
                        "name": "delegation",
                  "properties": {
                            "serviceName": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
                  }
                    }
              ]
            }
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2021-01-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "app",
      "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetName'))).subnets[0].id]",
        "httpsOnly": true,
        "siteConfig": {
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": true,
          "http20Enabled": true
        }
        },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnetName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- After deploying the template Go Back to azure portal and open the Resource group it will look like below

[image]

- Then open the app service navigate to networking as shown below.

[image]